# tcp socket server not sending

Tags: c++, sockets

I have this code, I run client from virtual machine on same PC it can connect but it will never receive LOGIN message, what could be the cause?

Not sure about send `flags` argument is set right.

```
static const char *LOGIN = "LOGIN\n";

int main()
{
    int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);

    //initialize structure
    bzero(&addr, addrlen);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(6666);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, addrlen);
    listen(s, 1);

    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addrlen = sizeof(client_addr);
    int c = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addrlen);

    char *msg = new char[15];

        //print client address
        char * buf = new char[16];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), buf, 16);
        cout << "Client connected: " << buf << endl;
        cout << "---------------------" << endl;

        send(c, LOGIN, sizeof(LOGIN), 0);

    close(c);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good start is to check for errors. All those system calls can return with a failure (they return the value `-1`), in which case you should check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to see what went wrong. You can use e.g. [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print out a message, or use [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string from an error code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change:

```
static const char *LOGIN = "LOGIN\n";
```

to:

```
static const char LOGIN[] = "LOGIN\n";
```

and the send call to:

```
send(c, LOGIN, sizeof(LOGIN)-1, 0);
```

The original call passed 4 (if on 32-bit system) because the `sizeof` was applied on pointer rather than on the string. The `-1` in the fixed version subtracts the terminating `'0'` from the string.

Comment: Or just use `strlen` instead.